# I am unable to log in to the backend of copy of the TYPO3 8.7.x page

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I made a copy of the entire TYPO3 8.7.X installation (file system, database). However, I can not log in to the administration panel. Every time the system rejects my attempt to log in.

What I have already tested (unsuccessfully):

- Using InstallTool I created a new user
- I changed the `loginSecurityLevel` value from `rsa` to `normal`
- I created a new user using plaintext in the database
- I've been cleaning the domain cookies in my browser
- I was cleaning the entire cache in `InstallTool`
- I removed the entire `typo3temp/` folder and cleared the `be_sessions`, `cache_md5params`, `fe_sessions`, `tx_rsaauth_keys` tables from `IntallTool` `Clean up` section

Any other ideas?  I log in to the original installation without any problems.

Comment: have you any extension which does a login based of external data? something like `ig_ldap_sso_auth`? these might intercept and ignore local users from local DB. (deactivate those Extensions)

Comment: I don't have anything like that installed

Comment: as you said you have made a copy of an installation: have you set a cookiedomain, which still might be the old domain and not the domain of your copy?

Comment: Does your webspace have any quota? If the quota is exceeded, TYPO3 might not be able to write session data to disk.

Comment: Is the system environment identical? Maybe the password hashing algorithm is not supported. See: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/PasswordHashing/Index.html